# I'm getting an error when pulling data from the Flutter Dio library

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:macistan/Standing.dart';

class InformationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InformationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<List<StandingElement>> getstanding() async {
    try {
      var response = await Dio().get(
        "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=203&season=2023",
        options: Options(headers: {
          'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
          'x-rapidapi-key': "7e75a8fd4dbc1400b449c8d5f8051cb0",
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = json.decode(response.toString());

        final standings = Standing.fromJson(data);

        return standings.response[0].standings; // Assuming you want the standings list.
      }
      return [];
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return [];
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 6,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text("hdslgfagwsıwplerguwgeŞIUwepıuy"),
              ),
              Container(),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                child: const TabBar(
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  isScrollable: true,
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(child: Text("Puan Durumu")),
                    Tab(child: Text("Form")),
                    Tab(child: Text("Fikstür")),
                    Tab(child: Text("İstatistik")),
                    Tab(child: Text("Transferler")),
                    Tab(child: Text("Haber")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    // Puan Durumu Tabı
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 10,
                                height: 30,
                                child: Text('#'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 15),
                              Container(
                                width: 120,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text('#Takım'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text('O'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text('G'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text('B'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text('M'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text('A'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text('Y'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text('AV'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: 20,
                                child: Text('P'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: FutureBuilder<List<StandingElement>>(
                              future: getstanding(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                    ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                  return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
                                } else if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                                    snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                                  return Text("No data available");
                                } else {
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      final standing =
                                      snapshot.data![index];
                                      return _buildTeamRow(
                                        standing.rank,
                                        standing.team.name,
                                        standing.points,
                                        standing.goalsDiff,
                                        standing.all.played,
                                        standing.all.win,
                                        standing.all.draw,
                                        standing.all.lose,
                                        standing.all.goals.goalsFor,
                                        standing.all.goals.against,
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(color: Colors.white), // Form Tabı
                    Container(color: Colors.purple), // Fikstür Tabı
                    Container(color: Colors.red), // İstatistik Tabı
                    Container(color: Colors.blue), // Transferler Tabı
                    Container(color: Colors.green), // Haber Tabı
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTeamRow(
      int Sira,
      String teamName,
      int O,
      int G,
      int B,
      int M,
      int A,
      int Y,
      int AV,
      int P) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$Sira"),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 10,
            height: 30,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$teamName"),
            width: 120,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$O"),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$G"),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$B"),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$M"),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$A"),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$Y"),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$AV"),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15),
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("$P"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my class

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Standing {
  final String standingGet;
  final Parameters parameters;
  final List<dynamic> errors;
  final int results;
  final Paging paging;
  final List<Response> response;

  Standing({
    required this.standingGet,
    required this.parameters,
    required this.errors,
    required this.results,
    required this.paging,
    required this.response,
  });

  factory Standing.fromRawJson(String str) => Standing.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Standing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Standing(
    standingGet: json["get"],
    parameters: Parameters.fromJson(json["parameters"]),
    errors: List<dynamic>.from(json["errors"].map((x) => x)),
    results: json["results"],
    paging: Paging.fromJson(json["paging"]),
    response: List<Response>.from(json["response"].map((x) => Response.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "get": standingGet,
    "parameters": parameters.toJson(),
    "errors": List<dynamic>.from(errors.map((x) => x)),
    "results": results,
    "paging": paging.toJson(),
    "response": List<dynamic>.from(response.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };

}

class Paging {
  final int current;
  final int total;

  Paging({
    required this.current,
    required this.total,
  });

  factory Paging.fromRawJson(String str) => Paging.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Paging.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Paging(
    current: json["current"],
    total: json["total"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "current": current,
    "total": total,
  };
}

class Parameters {
  final String league;
  final String season;

  Parameters({
    required this.league,
    required this.season,
  });

  factory Parameters.fromRawJson(String str) => Parameters.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Parameters.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Parameters(
    league: json["league"],
    season: json["season"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "league": league,
    "season": season,
  };
}

class Response {
  final League league;
  final List<StandingElement> standings;

  Response({
    required this.league,
    required this.standings,
  });

  factory Response.fromRawJson(String str) => Response.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Response(
    league: League.fromJson(json["league"]),
    standings: List<StandingElement>.from(json["standings"].map((x) => StandingElement.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "league": league.toJson(),
    "standings": List<dynamic>.from(standings.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class League {
  final int id;
  final Name name;
  final String country;
  final String logo;
  final String flag;
  final int season;

  League({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.country,
    required this.logo,
    required this.flag,
    required this.season,
  });

  factory League.fromRawJson(String str) => League.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory League.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => League(
    id: json["id"],
    name: nameValues.map[json["name"]]!,
    country: json["country"],
    logo: json["logo"],
    flag: json["flag"],
    season: json["season"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": nameValues.reverse[name],
    "country": country,
    "logo": logo,
    "flag": flag,
    "season": season,
  };
}

enum Name {
  SPER_LIG
}

final nameValues = EnumValues({
  "Süper Lig": Name.SPER_LIG
});

class StandingElement {
  final int rank;
  final Team team;
  final int points;
  final int goalsDiff;
  final Name group;
  final String form;
  final Status status;
  final String description;
  final All all;
  final All home;
  final All away;
  final DateTime update;

  StandingElement({
    required this.rank,
    required this.team,
    required this.points,
    required this.goalsDiff,
    required this.group,
    required this.form,
    required this.status,
    required this.description,
    required this.all,
    required this.home,
    required this.away,
    required this.update,
  });

  factory StandingElement.fromRawJson(String str) => StandingElement.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory StandingElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StandingElement(
    rank: json["rank"],
    team: Team.fromJson(json["team"]),
    points: json["points"],
    goalsDiff: json["goalsDiff"],
    group: nameValues.map[json["group"]]!,
    form: json["form"],
    status: statusValues.map[json["status"]]!,
    description: json["description"],
    all: All.fromJson(json["all"]),
    home: All.fromJson(json["home"]),
    away: All.fromJson(json["away"]),
    update: DateTime.parse(json["update"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rank": rank,
    "team": team.toJson(),
    "points": points,
    "goalsDiff": goalsDiff,
    "group": nameValues.reverse[group],
    "form": form,
    "status": statusValues.reverse[status],
    "description": description,
    "all": all.toJson(),
    "home": home.toJson(),
    "away": away.toJson(),
    "update": update.toIso8601String(),
  };
}

class All {
  final int played;
  final int win;
  final int draw;
  final int lose;
  final Goals goals;

  All({
    required this.played,
    required this.win,
    required this.draw,
    required this.lose,
    required this.goals,
  });

  factory All.fromRawJson(String str) => All.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory All.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => All(
    played: json["played"],
    win: json["win"],
    draw: json["draw"],
    lose: json["lose"],
    goals: Goals.fromJson(json["goals"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "played": played,
    "win": win,
    "draw": draw,
    "lose": lose,
    "goals": goals.toJson(),
  };
}

class Goals {
  final int goalsFor;
  final int against;

  Goals({
    required this.goalsFor,
    required this.against,
  });

  factory Goals.fromRawJson(String str) => Goals.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Goals.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Goals(
    goalsFor: json["for"],
    against: json["against"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "for": goalsFor,
    "against": against,
  };
}

enum Status {
  SAME
}

final statusValues = EnumValues({
  "same": Status.SAME
});

class Team {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String logo;

  Team({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.logo,
  });

  factory Team.fromRawJson(String str) => Team.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Team(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    logo: json["logo"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "logo": logo,
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> I/flutter (10969): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
> I/flutter (10969): {get: standings, parameters: {league: 203, season: 2023}, errors: [], resul...
> I/flutter (10969):  ^
> I/flutter (10969):

How can I get this error?
I can't find how to solve it.

I can write the response from the API to the screen, but I cannot decode it.

Comment: Pls post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Dio already decodes it and puts it in `response.data`, so you shouldn't decode it yourself, and definitely not the `response.toString()`.

So replace

```
    final data = json.decode(response.toString());

    final standings = Standing.fromJson(data);
```

with

```
    final standings = Standing.fromJson(response.data);
```

EDIT:
It also seems that you have errors in the structure of your data classes. Like you have that `Response` has a `league` and a `standings` but `standings` really is not a part of that in the api and is actually a field of `League`. Make sure you have it according to the api result.

Comment: This time it gave this error I/flutter (10969): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
I/flutter (10969): Receiver: null
I/flutter (10969): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => StandingElement)

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final standings = (json.decode(jsonEncode(response.data)) as List)
          .map((i) => Standing.fromJson(i))
          .toList();

      return standings;
    }
```

Explanation:

```
json.decode(jsonEncode(response.data)) 
//takes the data property from the response object and converts it to a JSON format. (response.data) presumably contains the raw JSON data received from the server

.asList()
//converts the JSON data into a list

.map((i) => Standing.fromJson(i))
//This part uses the map function to iterate through each item in the list and converts them into Dart objects of type "Standing" using the "fromJson" constructor of the Standing model class. "Standing" class is likely a custom class that defined to represent the data structure.

.toList()
//Finally, the result of the map operation is converted back into a Dart list, which contains instances of the Standing class

//then return the result list (standings)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**